# How is the derivation of the Constant Product AMM formula of Uniswap?

Tags: contract-development, uniswap, math, constant, amm

I was researching about **Uniswap v1** and I found that the code is using the following formula to get the amount out of a swap:

**Formula:**

[image: Formula used in code]

[Reference to code](https://github.com/Uniswap/v1-contracts/blob/master/contracts/uniswap_exchange.vy#L99-L111)

Everyone says that this formula is derived of this one, that we will call the ***'original formula'***:

[image: Original formula]

Honestly, I don't have a really strong math background but I can't see how can we derive the first formula from the second one. The further I arrived is here:

[image: Derived formula]

And it was thanks to this [article](https://devweb3.net/an-introduction-to-the-uniswap-v2-math-function/).

I've been searching for this on the internet for a while but I haven't found nothing.

ChatGPT told me that if you neglect the product of changes (`Δx * Δy`) it's possible to arrive to this formula:

[image: Derived formula neglecting product of changes]

But still, from the above formula to the one used in the actual code there's a difference ( `+ Δx`) in the numerator that I don't understand.

So, how did the uniswap team derived the formula used in the code from the 'original formula'?